# Looking for the title and author of a short story featuring paintings by Arcimboldo and a Habsburg conspiracy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, art, drug

I read this story a long time ago and I can’t for the life of me get it by googling.

Key details (these get somewhat spoilery if you haven't read this and feel like you might want to):

- Featured one of Gardner Dozois' Year's Best anthologies
- Female protagonist
- Set in near future
- Protagonist sent to ascertain authenticity of newly discovered Arcimboldo paintings, or something along those lines
- She is either drugged and the drug drives her insane, or goes insane naturally, or both
- She is attacked by men claiming to be protectors the Habsburg name and legacy
- Features a great bit where she interacts directly with one of the paintings' subjects during a hallucination

Thank you to anyone who can tell me the author and title.

Comment: Did it actually feature the paintings (as a picture), or just name-drop the painter?

Comment: There were no pictures, if that's what you mean, but the paintings are described in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The Coming of Vertumnus", by Ian Watson

***Featured one of Gardner Dozois' Year's Best anthologies***

Correct, the tenth annual edition.

***Female protagonist***

> Was I the Jill Donaldson who had written *Aesthetic Concupiscence*?

***Set in near future***

Although a year isn't mentioned, the exorbitant prices of London real estate and the technology level are consistent with the time period the story was written (1980s-1990s).

***Protagonist sent to ascertain authenticity of newly discovered Arcimboldo paintings, or something along those lines***

Close! She is an art critic paid to write an introduction to an art book of "newly discovered" Arcimboldos that are actually modern forgeries meant to discredit a Green movement using legitimate Arcimboldos as advertising.

***She is either drugged and the drug drives her insane, or goes insane naturally, or both***

> Immediately one hand pressed under my nose and another on my jaw, to force my mouth open.
>
> 'Drink!'
>
> Liquid poured down my throat -- some sweet concoction masking a bitter undertaste. I gagged and spluttered but had no choice except to swallow.
>
> *What had I drunk? What had I drunk?*

... and it's all downhill for her from there.

***She is attacked by men claiming to be protectors the Habsburg name and legacy***

> 'Libels against a certain Holy Roman Emperor, Miss Donaldson. Thus, libels against the Habsburg dynasty... which may yet be the salvation of Europe, and of the world. Very *untimely* libels.' The gent raised his cane and slashed it to and fro as if decapitating daisies. 'I am sure you will see reason to denounce your fabrications publicly...'

***Features a great bit where she interacts directly with one of the paintings' subjects during a hallucination***

> Until one day the door opened yet again, and golden light bathed my prison chamber.
>
> Vertumnus himself advanced--the fruitful God, his cheeks of ripe apple and peach, head crowned with fruit and grain, his chest a mighty pumpkin. His cherry and blackberry eyes glinted.
>
> Rudolph!
>
> He reached for me. Oh to be embraced by him! To be warmed.
>
> He lifted my paralyzed naked body from its dusty niche.

edit: This is the Vertumnus painting referenced: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertumnus_%28painting%29

Comment: that's the one! thanks very much! I really enjoyed this and I wanted to read it again.